# Diplexer termination?

Tags: filter, dummy-load

When using a 2M/70cm diplexer for low-pass filtering (or with only one antenna on one of the two "outputs"), should the unused connection be left open, or terminated?  (using a suitable impedance, such as a 50 Ohm resistor or dummy load?)

Answer (score 5):

Terminated! An open end would have a reflection coefficient of |R| = 1 (because, where would the energy go).

[image: Terminate]

Comment: It would reflect, yes, but is that unwanted? A typical two-port low-pass filter must also reflect as it has no resistive elements. Is the absorption more necessary in this case than the other for some reason?

Comment: Well, true, but there's certainly some amplifiers where you wouldn't want that to happen, energy coming back. Next aspect would of course also be that he'd explicitly get rid of the high-pass component – and leaving the port open would at least make it an (inefficient, since horribly mismatched to $120\pi\,\Omega$) antenna.